# How does Spring's JpaRepository find and connect to a DB server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I was navigating through the source code of Spring's reference application, [Sagan](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/). I am reading through the logic where Sagan extracts needed entity (e.g. [Post](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/blob/main/sagan-site/src/main/java/sagan/site/blog/Post.java)) from a relevant JpaRepository (e.g. [PostRepository](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/blob/main/sagan-site/src/main/java/sagan/site/blog/PostRepository.java)).

I am quite sure the such JpaRepositories do DB lookups for the client Spring classes, but the missing piece in my brain is, "How does JpaRepositories find and connect to a target database?"

For example, there may be multiple DB servers running on a same machine. They may even be of different implementations (some may be PostgreSQLs, and others may be MySQLs). Also, they may have databases with a table of a same name, and that might coincide with the table name declared in the `@Entity` classes.

So, how does JpaRepository sift through a sea of DB servers and find the right one and its table? I could not find any custom logics that connect the two from Sagan's codebase.

Comment: It doesn't. Sagan is a Spring Boot application and when run the datasource information (URL, user etc) is provided.

Comment: @M.Deinum Then, how does it accept such information? (through the console, or via a file?)

Comment: @M.Deinum Oh, I do it by stating it as a dependency. I see.

Comment: file, environment variables, can be anything. As mentioned it is a Spring Boot application which has a variety of ways to provide properties. If you combine it with Spring Cloud the possibilities grow.

Answer (score 1):

By default JpaRepository gets setting for DB connection from DataSourceProperties. One usually sets this settings in application.properties file. For exemple:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=user123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```